# AutoCompleteComboBox in Tkinter does not work with other languages. How can this be fixed?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

I found an example of the code for testing the algorithm on Stackoverflow. But I found that AutoCompleteComboBox does not add the rest of the word when entering into the list of words on a different keyboard layout.

This code with English list works well.

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteCombobox # pip install ttkwidgets


lst = [
    'C', 'C++', 'Java',
    'Python', 'Perl',
    'PHP', 'ASP', 'JS'
]

root = Tk()

# creating Combobox
combo_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=30, completevalues=lst)

combo_box.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

When I use a different language, Autocomplete Combobox does not work.

```
lst = [
    'Хлеб', 'Картошка', 'Соль',
    'Молоко', 'Макароны',
    'Яйца', 'Мясо'
]
```

[image]

Comment: weird, it works on my computer

Comment: @AchilleG with lst = ['Хлеб', 'Картошка', 'Соль', 'Молоко', 'Макароны', 'Яйца', 'Мясо']?